# Removing plugins from a .pkg file

Tags: macos, packagemaker

I am using an user registration plugin that is included in iceberg installer. Registration dialog is appeared and everything works fine in the installer.

But the problem here is when i right click the .pkg file and go to "Show Package contents" there is the plugin folder which i included in the package and i can delete this simply.

Is there a way to prevent this by disabling "Show Packages Contents" or any other ways available to prevent this ?

Also there is "Flat Package Editor" in which we can remove the files within the package created using "Package Maker".

Is there a way to prevent this also ?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not restrict a user to delete any content inside your application bundle.
However, you can use digital signatures to mitigate the problem.
Make sure that the installer is signed before you ship it. In that case, if a user deletes any content from inside the bundle, OSX will complain that the app is broken.

But, be aware that a person having decent knowledge about .pkg files can still bypass your registration.
For example, if I do a silent installation of your pkg, it will not show me the registration dialog.

You should probably look at implementing this registration inside your application as well. So, if a user bypasses the registration in your installer, your application must be able to detect that and show the popup again.